# Attempt to retrieve access token response from microsoft graph fails in the browser

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I am trying to get an access token from Microsoft graph API in my React App. The following is the request I make, but it returns a *400 Bad Request* error. I tried this in POSTman and could get an access token response, but fails in the browser. Any helpful advice is highly appreciated.

```js
  function getAccessToken(){
    const getTokenURL = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token?scope=user.read%20Calendars.ReadWrite&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F3000%2Foutlook`

    const params = new URLSearchParams();

    params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
    params.append('code', outlookCode); //this comes from a `useState` variable
    params.append('client_id',process.env.REACT_APP_OUTLOOK_APP_ID);
    params.append('client_secret', process.env.REACT_APP_OUTLOOK_SECRET_KEY);

    console.log(params) // this prints {} in the console
    axios.post(getTokenURL, params,{
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }).then(res => console.log(res.data)).catch(err => console.log(err))

}
```

Comment: you **SHOULD** never use this flow in the browser!! Have a look at the possible flows in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the [OAuth Authorization Code grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/authorization-code/) from a browser. It is required the ability to receive an HTTP request which clearly a browser cannot do.

You need to use the [OAuth Implicit grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/) for this.